# Python - Delete lines from dataframe (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to delete certain information from a data frame, but the 'delete-command' (.drop) does not work like it should anyone got an idea?

My Code:

```
    import pandas as pd

def join():

    open_momox_xlsx = "momox_ergebnisse.xlsx"
    open_rebuy_xlsx = "rebuy_ergebnisse.xlsx"

    rebuy_xlsx = pd.read_excel(open_rebuy_xlsx)
    momox_xlsx = pd.read_excel(open_momox_xlsx)

    rebuy_data = rebuy_xlsx[['ReBuy']]
    isbn_data = rebuy_xlsx[['ISBN']]
    momox_data = momox_xlsx[['Momox']]

    dataframe = pd.DataFrame =({'ISBN': isbn_data, 'Rebuy': rebuy_data, 'Momox': momox_data})
    data = pd.concat(dataframe,axis=1, ignore_index=True)

    c=0
    #print(data[0])
    while c < len(data):

        if data[1][c] and data[2][c] == '///':
            data.drop(index=c)
        elif data[1][c] and data[2][c] < '1':
            data.drop(index=c)
        elif data[1][c] or data[2][c] < '1' and data[1][c] or data[2][c] == '///' :
            data.drop(index=c)
        c=c+1
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
                0      1      2
0   9783630876672  12,35   2.62
1   9783423282789  11,67   6.07
2   9783833879500  17,25  12.40
3   9783898798822   6,91   1.16
4   9783453281417  12,93   2.84
5   9783630876672  12,35   4.08
6   9783423282789  11,67   6.07
7   9783833879500  17,25   9.94
8   9783898798822   6,91   2.96
9   9783453281417  12,93   2.68
10     3927905909    ///    ///
11     3872948210    ///   0.15
12  9783293003781    ///   0.15
13  9783423246842    ///    ///
14  9783423247146    ///    ///
15  9783423246934    ///    ///
16     387294116x    ///    ///
17  9783935597456   0,16   0.15
18  9783423204545    ///    ///
```

Wanted Output:

```
                0      1      2
0   9783630876672  12,35   2.62
1   9783423282789  11,67   6.07
2   9783833879500  17,25  12.40
3   9783898798822   6,91   1.16
4   9783453281417  12,93   2.84
5   9783630876672  12,35   4.08
6   9783423282789  11,67   6.07
7   9783833879500  17,25   9.94
8   9783898798822   6,91   2.96
9   9783453281417  12,93   2.68
```

the if-statement seems to work properly, but the data.drop does not do what it should..

Comment: try with inplace parameter...i.e `data.drop(index=c,inplace=True)` or `data=data.drop(index=c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a clean dataframe and **keep** values you want:

```
data[['1', '2']] = data[['1', '2']].replace({"///": np.nan, ",": "."}, regex=True)
                                   .astype(float)
data = data.loc[data[["1", "2"]].ge(1.).all(axis="columns")]
```

```
>>> data
               0      1      2
0  9783630876672  12.35   2.62
1  9783423282789  11.67   6.07
2  9783833879500  17.25  12.40
3  9783898798822   6.91   1.16
4  9783453281417  12.93   2.84
5  9783630876672  12.35   4.08
6  9783423282789  11.67   6.07
7  9783833879500  17.25   9.94
8  9783898798822   6.91   2.96
9  9783453281417  12.93   2.68
```

**Comments:**

**1st line:**

- [`data[['1', '2']]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) select columns named '1' and '2'
- [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) change existing values ('///' and ',') by new ones ('nan' and '.')
- [`astype(float)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) convert your string columns to real numbers (float) since your dataframe is cleaned.

**2nd line:**

- `data.loc[...]` locate something in your dataframe
- `data[["1", "2"]].ge(1.).all(axis="columns")`: in columns '1' and '2', search values 'greater than or equal 1 and it must be true for 'all columns' of the row.

Comment: Thanks for the help as well! That seems to be exactly what I need right now, but tbh i dont really understand that code, sorry i've just started in python. Where would i need to put that in my code? just instead of the data.drop behind the if/elif-statements?

Comment: To use this code replace lines from `c=0` to `c=c+1`

Comment: That worked perfectly fine, thank you! I had to edit my code a little, now I have one column more, but I want to ignore it in this line `data[["1", "2"]].ge(1.).all(axis="columns")` so I don't care if the value of the new column is >=1 , I just need the data which is in column 1 and 2 greater than or equal to 1. Could u maybe help me out with rewriting that line? Would be really grateful!  I know that it has to be the .all(axis="columns") part but when i try to put the names of the columns instead it doesn't work… And thank you for the explanation that really helped to understand it a bit!

Answer (score 4):

You should add `inplace=True` to `drop` function.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now the .drop works but it keeps the data i wanted to delete, and deletes the data I wanted to keep, but i guess that makes sense bc i say data.drop and then print(data) - which seems to be the dropped data, is there any simple way to turn that around? I guess I could just change up the if-statement so that the data i want to keep gets dropped, and that dropped data gets printed out.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the advice with `data.drop(index=c, inplace=True)` little bit better, you could think of it as assigning the result back to the same variable: `data = data.drop(index=c)`. Although the approach with `inplace=True` is usually be better, both should work.